# Distinct eigenvalues for integral operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Is there some sufficient condition on the kernel $K$ of a (say, finite rank, to simplify) integral operator
$$
\mathcal K:f(x)\in L^2(\mathbb R)\mapsto \int K(x,y)f(y)dy
$$
so that it has all its non-zero eigenvalues $\textbf{distinct}$ (i.e. with multiplicity one) ?

Comment: I can refer you to this [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1994087).

Comment: A finite-rank operator on an infinite-dimensional Banach space has infinite-dimensional kernel. Are you talking about the nonzero eigenvalues?